# Do "standing"/90° MicroSD card slots exist?

Tags: connector, sd

For a rather cramped design, I need a way to hold a MicroSD card in a "standing"/"upright" position (90° to the PCB, rather than "flat"/"parallel" like most sockets). The card will be plugged and removed very seldomly, probably only once, so I don't care too much about the usability aspects of such a design.

Can anybody point me at a socket like this, if it even exists at all?

Comment: I would suggest using a website like digi-key with filtering to look for it although I can't say I've ever seen one.

Comment: do image search for `vertical micro sd` ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=vertical+micro+sd&iar=images&ia=images

Comment: I've seen them for full-size SD cards, but haven't for micro SD.

Answer (score 1):

If you cant find one, you could try making a very small pcb that holds a SMD SD card holder, with an edge connector on the PCB that can orient it vertically.